# Connecting Scarlett 2i2 to mixer

Tags: macbook-pro, logic

I want to set up my MacBook to do the following:

-Acquire input from a Scarlett 2i2 audio interface;

-Process the signal using Bias Amp or Amplitube (or some other softwares for Guitar);

-Send it to a mixer which is connected to power speakers;

I simply don't know which way I should connect the Scarlett 2i2 interface to send the processed signal to the mixer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect the sound card with the amplifier you have to use two jack to jack cable with diameter 6.35 mm.

The type of the cables should be with three pole to carry balanced signals (but it works either with two pole cables).

The connection must be made from the lines output placed on the rear of the audio interface to the input of a power amplifier or a mixer.